# How to solve FTP continues loading

Tags: visual-studio, ftp, cpanel

I use the sftp extension in vscode. When I tried to connect my workspace with server, It not showing any error just loading. I have a ftp account on my cPanel.

[sftp error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaJwG.png)

[sftp config file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hToMw.png)

Answer (score 0):

This problem most often occurs due to DNS Server and to solve the problem you can use the IP address server in the host section.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).